# Not able to access WSDL even though HTTPGetEnabled is set to true

Tags: c#, wcf, wsdl, windows-services

I created a windows service and installed it using installutil.exe.

But I am not able to access 'MEX' endpoint even though HTTPGetEnabled is set to true.
Always getting the error 'Metadata publishing for this service is currently disabled.'

Could you please help me with this issue.

Below is my App.Config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
      <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
          <behavior name ="MyBehaviour">
            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
      </behaviors>
        <services>
            <service name="GenerateResult.GenerateResult" behaviorConfiguration="MyBehaviour">
                <endpoint address="http://localhost:5050/GetResultService" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                    bindingConfiguration="" contract="GenerateResult.IGenerateResult" />
                <endpoint address="http://localhost:5050/GetResultService/mex" 
                    binding="mexHttpBinding"
                    bindingConfiguration="" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        </service>    
    </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 0):

We need to set an HTTP base address to enable the `httpGetEnabled` attribute although we have set the `serviceMetadata` property.
Please refer to the below code segment.

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service  name="ConsoleApp3.TestService" behaviorConfiguration="mybeh"> 
        <endpoint address="myservice" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="ConsoleApp3.ITestService" bindingConfiguration=""></endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" bindingConfiguration=""></endpoint>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:21011/"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
   <basicHttpBinding>
   </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="mybeh">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.
**Updated.**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Uri uri = new Uri("http://localhost:21011");
            BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
            using (ServiceHost sh = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService), uri))
            {
                sh.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService), binding, "");
                ServiceMetadataBehavior smb;
                smb = sh.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceMetadataBehavior>();
                if (smb == null)
                {
                    smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior()
                    {
                        HttpGetEnabled = true
                    };
                    sh.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);
                }
                Binding mexbinding = MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexHttpBinding();
                sh.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMetadataExchange), mexbinding, "mex");
                sh.Opened += delegate
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Service is ready");
                };
                sh.Closed += delegate
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Service is clsoed");
                };
                sh.Open();
                Console.ReadLine();
                //pause
                sh.Close();
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
```

Comment: Hi Abraham... thanks for your reply
But still, I am facing the same issue.

Below is the OnStart() method for the windows service.

protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            sh = new ServiceHost(typeof(GetResultService), new Uri("http://localhost:5050/GetResultService"));
            sh.Open();
        }

Is this playing any role in disabling the Metadata?

Comment: Possible, If you use Console Application to host the service, please refer to the above code.

Comment: Thanks, Abraham... the above code is working fine and i am able to access wsdl, but I am having one query. When I try to add configuration by the imperative way(By code), I am able to access WSDL but getting issues while adding configuration to app.config file

Comment: I didn’t get your point, Please go on sharing your situation. 
the service host created in the OnStart method will automatically take the settings of the `appconfig` when we didn't set up the service configuration programmatically.
If it helps, please mark the reply as an answer.